# Decklink frame conversion to opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am calling frames from a Blackmagic Decklink capture card and trying to convert them to a `cv::Mat`.

I have this working, but the resulting frames look like this:

[image]

When they should look like this:

[image]

The incoming frames are valid, so it must be my conversion. Based on this question:

[Getting left and right frames with BlackMagic SDK and convert them into opencv mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466024/getting-left-and-right-frames-with-blackmagic-sdk-and-convert-them-into-opencv-m)

I am using:

```
bool deckLinkVideoFrameToCvMat(ComPtr<IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame> in,
    cv::Mat& out)
{

    void* data;
    if (FAILED(in->GetBytes(&data))) {
        std::cout << "Fail obtaining the data from videoFrame\n" << std::endl;
        return S_FALSE;
    }


    cv::Mat loadedImage;

    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(in->GetHeight(), in->GetWidth(), CV_8UC2, data, in->GetRowBytes());
    cv::cvtColor(mat, loadedImage, CV_YUV2BGR_UYVY);


    loadedImage.copyTo(out);


    return true;
}
```

Where am i going wrong?

EDIT: with the stride parameter removed, as suggested:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the Blackmagic image is `UYVY`? You can experiment with different options: `YUYV` and `YVYU`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried those, and the colours change (as expected), but the vertical lines / noise stay the same. Would that mean it is the step value that is incorrect?

Comment: new image uploaded, using just: `cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(in->GetHeight(), in->GetWidth(), CV_8UC2, data);`

Comment: Have you tried all variations of `cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_`? Like this one `cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422`?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I tried all the possible COLOR_YUV2BGR_ values, colors are always off.